# What files in the LevelDB folder are append-only?

Tags: append, attr, leveldb, rocksdb

In my LevelDB-folder at some stage I have the following files:

```
000004.log  000005.ldb  CURRENT  LOCK  LOG  MANIFEST-000002
```

I don't think they are all append-only? So it's certainly not possible to run " chattr +a * " on all files in the database folder, because some are deleted, while running leveldb.
My question is which files won't be deleted and are append only during a normal LevelDB session and during compaction and are those files which are deleted before deletion append-only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*.log: append-only while WAL, the filename will change
*.ldb: static once generate, the filename will change

MANIFEST-*: static once generate, the suffix will change
LOG: append-only, rotate per day by default
CURRENT: rewrite after version change
LOCK: only change when open or close

to answer your question:

> Q1: is which files won't be deleted and are append only during a normal
>   LevelDB session?
>   A1: No, there isn't such file(maybe LOG, but it will rotate)

---

> Q2: are those files which are deleted before deletion append-only
>   A2: *.log is append only before deletion